# Visual Studio 2012 Update 2 appears in French?

Tags: visual-studio-2012

On my main PC, when I try to install Visual Studio 2012 Update 2, the dialog appears in French:

[image: Visual Studio 2012 Update 2 in French]

That's fine, but I'm not French, I'm in the UK. It's not clear if I accept this will I end up with a French version of Visual Studio 2012?!?

On my laptop I get the english version - so I'm wondering why the French version on my main PC (which is setup as UK English)?

I tried

```
vs2012.2 /help
```

and I get the following:

```
Programme d'installation - Utilisation

    Ce programme d'installation prend en charge les commutateurs suivants :

    /Help              Affiche ce texte d'utilisation.
    /H
    /?

    /Quiet             Mode silencieux sans affichage et sans interaction de
l'utilisateur.
    /Q
    /Silent
    /S

    /Passive           Affiche la progression, mais n'attend pas de saisie
utilisateur.
    /Qb

    /PromptRestart     Invite l'utilisateur à redémarrer le système.

    /NoRestart         NoRestart      Ne redémarre pas le système pendant ou
après une installation.

    /ForceRestart      Redémarre toujours le système après une installation.


    /Log               <nom de fichier> Spécifie l'emplacement du fichier
journal.
    /L

    /Uninstall         Désinstalle le produit.
    /U

    /Uninstall /Force  Désinstalle le produit ainsi que les fonctionnalités
partagées avec d'autres produits.
    /U /Force          Avertissement : l'utilisation de ce commutateur peut
entraîner un fonctionnement incorrect des autres produits installés sur cet 
ordinateur.

    /Repair            Répare le produit.

    /Layout            Crée une copie du support dans le dossier indiqué.

    /NoWeb             Empêche le programme d'installation de télécharger
sur Internet.

    /Full              Installe toutes les fonctionnalités du produit.

    /AdminFile         <nom de fichier> Spécifie le fichier de contrôle 
d'in stallation.

    /CustomInstallPath <chemin d'accès>
                       Définit un emplacement d'installation personnalisé

    /ProductKey        <clé produit de 25 caractères>
                       Définit une clé produit personnalisée (sans tirets)

    Pour plus d'informations, consultez le site
http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=235127&clcid=0x40C
```

I did search for the update on the web, and selected english, but whatever I downloaded still appeared in French.

Comment: See it as a learning opportunity? :-)

Comment: What is the default location shown in the following settings: _Control Panel\All Control Panel Items\Location and Other Sensors\Default Location_?

Comment: Off topic? What are you people smoking? The [FAQ] says questions about "software tools commonly used by programmers" are on topic. Who else do you think uses Visual Studio?

Comment: I looked at Control Panel\All Control Panel Items\Location and Other Sensors and I see "No sensors are installed", so I can't access Default Location.

Comment: My question has been migrated from Stackoverflow. I've been given no reason as to why this is the case. Also, I didn't have an account on SuperUser, so I had to create one. I see that I can't ask questions here as my reputation is too low.

Comment: @imekon - What language packs do you have on your main pc?  Your question was moved because it has to do with a software problem and is not a programming question.

Comment: From what I remember when I installed it English (US) and English (UK). I don't think I've installed anything else.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had the same problem—Update 2 insisted on running in French on two different machines.  After poring over log files and Process Monitor output, I tried the following, and it worked.

Run regedit and set the value of the key `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\VisualStudio\11.0\General\UILanguage` 
to 0.  Then run VS2012.2.exe again.

Your mileage may vary, of course.

Comment: I had 0x40c in UILanguage. Once I cleared it, the update was in English. 8)

Comment: Worked for VS2012.4.exe also. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure which one you're downloading, as you didn't give us a link. But I just did a Google search for the update, found [this one](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=38188) that claims to be in English, and sure enough it is (at least on my machine).

[image: Works on My Machine] …and all that

I'm pretty sure that the setup program doesn't change its language based on your system settings. I think it's hard-coded, depending on the version you download. So it shouldn't matter what language your system is configured to use.

Comment: The first link came from VS 2012 itself, so I went looking for the update via Google. As I said, on my main PC it is in French, on my Laptop it is in English.